# Unable to fetch date object at salary rules using Odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I am trying to define a salary rule which will calculate the salary of employee on the base of date_to and date_from But in these object. I am only able get days. By using days I can get worked days from them. I am unable to get month year there.

```
datej = str(payslip.date_to)
datek = str(payslip.date_from)
dj = datej[-2:]
dk = datek[-2:]
working_days=dj-dk
one_daySalary=contract.wage/30
salary=working_days*one_daySalary
result = salary
```

I am only able to calculate the salary on bases of fixed 30 days month.

Comment: for me, I extend (inheritance) the `hr.employee` object, and called whatever methods I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found the month in payslip.name .Then i simple tried that is month in that payslip name or not but in this solution we have to force user not to change payslip name pattern . I had changed the payslip name to read only  to achieve this

```
 datej = str(payslip.date_to)
    datek = str(payslip.date_from)
    dj = int(datej[-2:])
    dk = int(datek[-2:])
    working_days=dj - dk
    month=0
    if "January" in payslip.name: month= 31
    if "February" in payslip.name: month= 28
    if "March" in payslip.name: month= 31
    if "April" in payslip.name: month= 30
    if "May" in payslip.name: month= 31
    if "June" in payslip.name: month= 30
    if "July" in payslip.name: month= 31
    if "August" in payslip.name: month= 31
    if "September" in payslip.name: month= 30
    if "October" in payslip.name: month= 31
    if "November" in payslip.name: month= 30
    if "December" in payslip.name: month= 31
    one_daySalary=contract.wage/month
    salary=one_daySalary*working_days
    result = salary
```

Comment: Take a look to the [date python methods](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html) or odoo date methods. Your code maybe work, but you are programming badly

Comment: i am using odoo available object there . direct python modules are available there .

Comment: Your code will fail if the year is an leap-year, thats why the are well done libraries like time, datetime, etc for python, like @ChesuCr says, 'you are programming badly'.

Comment: Well, actually I have never worked with salary rules. I am curious, where do you access to these salary rules? Are they different from the security rules? It looks like there is a special sandbox and you only can use some functions. Can you use the object `time` in these rules? that may help you

Comment: No i cannot use Object time there . Odoo had provided a set of object we only can use them .

Answer (score 2):

You can get both month and year if you import `datetime` library and convert the dates to `datetime` objects. I guess `payslip.date_to` should be a string before you do `str(payslip.date_to)`, so you can do this using Odoo special methods:

```
datej = fields.Date.from_string(payslip.date_to)
datek = fields.Date.from_string(payslip.date_from)
```

Now you have two `datetime` objects and you can use `datetime` methods to get what you want.

```
>>> datej.month
1
>>> datej.year
2018
```

Comment: But Odoo didn't allow me to import datetime library.

Comment: @HassanALi can't you write at the top of your file `import datetime`?

Comment: Do you get an error just because you're importing `datetime` or because of executing `fields.Date.from_string` method?

Comment: in odoo at salary rule We only execute available objects.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to tell me. I guess you're writing Python code in a `*.py` file, so, `import datetime` should work if you write it at the top of the file out of the classes.

Comment: no i am writing code at odoo salary rules not in .py

Comment: Mmm I don't get what you mean when you say salary rule, may be some kind of new interface option for v11? I don't know it so far.

Comment: yes of course its a interface option where we can do calculation on available objects there

Answer (score 0):

On top of the program , `import datetime` library. and using its  method if the object of date you received is in string format,convert it into proper format using the following function.

```
timeFormattedObject = timeObject.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
timeFormattedObject = datetime.strptime(timeFormattedObject ,DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
```

For getting the year of that object use the following function.

```
yearValue = timeFormattedObject.year
```

Comment: sorry but this not implementable at odoo .

Comment: This is applicable in python file. I have implemented it. Can you elaborate,how is it not working.